# JavaFX ListView selection listener problems

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listener

I am beginner in Java FX, and I have some troubles with change listener with List View. I tried almost everything and nothing works.

Here's the report from debugger:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ukolnicek_mp2.FXMLDocumentController$1.changed(FXMLDocumentController.java:97)
at ukolnicek_mp2.FXMLDocumentController$1.changed(FXMLDocumentController.java:85)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:404)
at ukolnicek_mp2.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:105)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
```

The full error log is here:

https://pastebin.com/raw/Jk5v5XUj

Comment: Send us an example of your code so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: more specifically: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Here is the whole repo.

I dont know where exactly is the problem, sorry guys :( 

https://github.com/vholub/ukolnicek-mp3-git

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To sum it up it is a Minimal(small amount of code) Complete(Fully runnable) Verifiable(I can put into my IDE and run without expected errors) Example(Recreate your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in .fxml document. I recently renamed one @FXML variable and I forgot to reassign it in the scene builder.